# Field resolver in Appsync using the same query output as argument

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, resolver

> GraphQL Schema:

```
type Query {
      getCustomer(customerId:Int!):Customer
}
type Customer {
      customerId : Int
      customerName : String
      emailId: String
      orderId: Int
      orderDetails(limit:Int):[OrderDetails]
}
type OrderDetails {
      orderId: Int
      productId: Int
      quantityOrdered: Int
      totalCost: Int
}
```

> GraphQL query:

```
query getCustomer {
   getCustomer(customerId:100){
      customerName
      orderId
      orderDetails(limit:1){
          quantityOrdered
      }
   }
}
```

In this scenario. **Customer** table has only 4 columns : **customerId, customerName, emailId, orderId** but I need to hit an OrderDetails table if that is asked in the query. So I have written a Field Resolver for **orderDetails** and this orderDetails will take input from the **customer** data

> Request Mapping Template of orderDetails Resolver

```
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "GetItem",
    "key": {
        "orderId": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.orderId),
    }
}
```

[for better understanding of my issue check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvXA1.png)

How do I use this orderId from the same query as a input for the **field resolver (OrderDetails table)** ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$ctx.source.orderId` in your resolver for orderDetails.